# SQL Trigger Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I want to trigger an Update on multiple sql tables without creating a loop.
Lets say I have 2 tables:

```
Table: User_Names
---------------
|Name | Clark |
|Gen  |  Male |
|id   |     1 |
---------------

Table: User_Ages
---------------
|Age  |     34|
|Gen  |  Male |
|id   |     1 |
---------------
```

The id's are unique and refer to the same person.
I want to update the column**Gen** in User_Names, my trigger should update it in the other Table.
 
I also want this to happen when I change it in User_Ages Table, But if both update eachother im creating a loop on the Update trigger in mysql. How do I prevent this loop? 
**The point here is creating a SQL Trigger.**

Comment: Why do you store redundant data at all? Databases are usually used to avoid that, you know?

Comment: This is an example of what I am trying to achieve, no actual data I'm using is shown here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to address your original question given the nature of your example. This is a normalization issue much more than trigger issue.

In this case you should normalize your data and only store it in one place. Example above also suggests that you have slight misunderstanding on how to use rows and columns.

Given the example, better layout would probably be:

```
Table: User_names
+----+---------+------+
| id | Name    | gen  |
+----+---------+------+
| 1  | Clark   | Male |
+----+---------+------+


Table: User_Ages
+----+------+
| id | age  |
+----+------+
| 1  | 34   |
+----+------+
```

When you want to retrieve both values, you'd just link them in your query, e.g.

```
SELECT user_names.id,name,gen,age FROM User_names JOIN User_Ages USING (id);
```

Would give you:

```
+----+---------+------+-----+
| id | Name    | gen  | age |
+----+---------+------+-----+
| 1  | Clark   | Male | 34  |
+----+---------+------+-----+
```

---

Coming back to your original question: In situation like that I'd question the original design. If it is really called for, then I'd pick one table that acts as a master and propagates the changes to other table. E.g. define the trigger on User_names table and use it to populate User_Ages table as well.

Comment: Im trying to create a SQl Trigger, The Queries are not the problem.

Comment: I typed some columns so i could create an example. I need to knwo how to get a trigger on both columns wihout triggering eachother

Comment: You already realized what's the problem with it. Why on earth do you want to do this? I'd say, what we have here is a typical xy-problem. Read about it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem If you really really insist on having this odd "functionality", write a stored procedure.

Comment: What i want to achieve here is that when "Something is updated" in Table "A" i also want to update something in Table "B" and the other way around.